# 'sudo apt-get update' does not work after trying to install elasticsearch through apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, apt

First, I tried to install elasticsearch according to the instructions on the website
**https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/deb.html**

but after `echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-8.x.list`

```
deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/apt stable main
```

but after that, when I try to `$ sudo apt-get update`

```
> E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source
> https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/apt/ stable:
> /usr/share/keyrings/elasticsearch-keyring.gpg != E: The list of
> sources could not be read.
```

but in keyrings, there is no elasticsearch-keyring.gpg

in keyrings,

```
docker-archive-keyring.gpg      
ubuntu-advantage-ros.gpg   
ubuntu-advantage-cc-eal.gpg                
ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg   
ubuntu-advantage-cis.gpg               
ubuntu-archive-removed-keys.gpg    
ubuntu-advantage-esm-apps.gpg          
ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring.gpg   
ubuntu-advantage-esm-infra-trusty.gpg  
ubuntu-cloudimage-removed-keys.gpg    
ubuntu-advantage-fips.gpg              
ubuntu-master-keyring.gpg
```

I already changed the file sources.list from /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/ to /etc/apt/
for reset the list

I don't know how to get it back. I can't install any package through apt now

someone please, help me T_T

Answer (score 4):

I am by no means a linux or elasticsearch expert. I don't know if this is a GOOD solution. It could be a very nasty and BAD solution.

...But it allowed me to use apt-get again when I was having the same problem. Who knows, maybe the people who actually know the "correct" solution will respond if I trigger them with a dirty hack, haha.

In /etc/apt/sources.list.d, there's a file called "elastic-8.x.list", the same one used in the command you used above for installation. I removed the file and I could use apt-get again.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-8.x.list
```

I also removed the elasticsearch keyring, but that on it's own didn't work. It was removing the elastic list file that allowed things to work again.

```
sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/elasticsearch-keyring.gpg
```

I hope my answer was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation when trying to install Kibana after installing the Elasticsarch. Try these steps:

1. Edit file: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-8.x.list`
2. Delete the following line: `deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/elasticsearch-keyring.gpg] https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/apt stable main`
3. Re-install Kibana

Answer (score 0):

For me there was repeating `deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/apt stable main` removing those repeating code worked.

Answer (score 0):

The below steps worked for me.

STEP-1: Remove gpg file

```
rm /usr/share/keyrings/elastic.gpg
```

STEP-2 Remove this entry

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/elastic.gpg] https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main
```

from
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list

STEP-3

```
apt-get update
```